# Change the user profile's bounty tab's appearance and interactivity a bit

Tags: feature-request, bounties, profile-page, user-interface

On hovering over any bounty, one of the following texts will be displayed based on whether the bounty is still active or not:

- "this question had a bounty worth XYZ reputation"
- "this question has an open bounty worth XYZ reputation"

I feel that these texts are redundant because they convey no extra meaning that isn't already there except tell the user whether the bounty is open/not open without the user having to click through to the question.

I thought that instead of these messages, displaying the reason for a bounty instead of whether the bounty is still open or not, and having the color of the bounty icon changed to reflect whether the bounty is open or not  would be better.

---

**Currently, the bounty tab looks like:**

[image: Current "Bounty" tab in a user's profile page]

**After the changes I propose, the bounty tab could look like:**

[image: Proposed "Bounty" tab in a user's profile page]

---

<sub>**Note:** In the above two examples, the first two bounties have expired. The third one is still active.</sub>

Comment: Not a bad idea but why not display both pieces of informaiton, like "this question has an open bounty worth 50 reputation because it has not received enough attention".

Comment: @Aziz, I just thought it might be cleaner to let the color of the bounty tab infer that. At least for me, whenever I see something lighter in a place where things could have been uniform, my brain automatically parses that as something that has passed/expired!

Comment: @Aziz the 50 reputation bounty is already strongly implied by the bounties tab and the +50 bounty icon, it just makes the message unnecessarily long.

Comment: @3ventic valid point but tooltips on Stack Exchange sites generally repeat information and add some details to it. For example, hover on badge count, it will show `# gold/silver badges`